# SELinux implementation in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, selinux

How does Ubuntu implements SELinux...? what are the pacakges(modules) involved in implementation of SELinux on Ubuntu

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> How does Ubuntu implements SELinux...?

`selinux` is not installed or enabled by default. We use [apparmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/Main_Page) by [default](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppArmor). The [Ubuntu wiki page for SELinux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux)  even claims ...

> **Warning**
>
> The Ubuntu-specific "selinux" and "selinux-policy-ubuntu" packages documented here have not received much attention since Karmic, and appear to be effectively broken in Precise.
>
> If you wish to use SELinux in Ubuntu, the "selinux-basics" and "selinux-policy-default" packages from Debian are still being actively maintained. Documentation relevant to those packages can be found at http://wiki.debian.org/SELinux

but also contains instruction on how to install it:

> **[SELinux in Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux)**
>
> SELinux can be enabled in Ubuntu by installing the "selinux"
>   meta-package, which will make the needed changes to the system, and
>   install the Tresys policies for Ubuntu:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install selinux
> ```
>
> After installation, you will be prompted to reboot the system to label
>   and activate SELinux.

But it might be smarter to install the debian packages manually...

---

> What are the packages(modules) involved?

- [packages related to selinux](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/selinux).
- [packages related to selinux-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/selinux-utils).
- [packages related to selinux-policy-ubuntu](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/selinux-policy-ubuntu).

Comment: thanx a lot....

Comment: do you mean that ubuntu is safe enough without using SELinux because of app armour is preinstalled on it??

Comment: Ubuntu installs itself as safe as possible. apparmor is a tool for that and yes, you basically do not need selimux (apparmor is an alternative of selinux (there are more: tomoyo is another one)).

Comment: If you wist to use selinux, I highly advise you use Fedora. selinux is maintained in Fedora, active by default, and there are a greater number of tools to manage selinux, both graphical and command line. If you wish to use Ubuntu, as suggested, use Apparmor. both tools have a bit of a learning curve and both have advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: A good high-level comparison of AppArmor vs SELinux: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29378/comparison-between-apparmor-and-selinux  On that basis, it may not necessarily be a bad idea to stick with AppArmor...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you have to remove apparmor before installing SELinux:

```
sudo apt-get remove apparmor
```

According to the [SELinux wiki page](http://selinuxproject.org/page/Guide/Installation):

> Starting with Hardy Heron SELinux has been integrated into Ubuntu and can be installed via apt.
>
> Install the selinux package:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install selinux
> ```
>
> Change the SELinux mode in /etc/selinux/config (optional):
>
> > - Enforcing
> >
> >   ```
> >   sudo sed -i 's/SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=enforcing/' /etc/selinux/config
> >   ```
> > - Permissive
> >
> >   ```
> >   sudo sed -i 's/SELINUX=.*/SELINUX=permissive/' /etc/selinux/config
> >   ```
>
> Reboot
>
> During shutdown all of the files on the system will be labeled. This may take some time depending on how many files you have and disk speed.

A search using `apt-cache search` turns up these packages:

```
postgresql-contrib-9.4 - additional facilities for PostgreSQL
ruby-selinux - Ruby bindings to SELinux shared libraries
checkpolicy - SELinux policy compiler
debian-handbook - reference book for Debian users and system administrators
joe-jupp - reimplement the joe Debian package using jupp
jupp - user friendly full screen text editor
libseaudit-dev - Security Enhanced Linux audit message parser development
libseaudit4 - Security Enhanced Linux audit message parsing library
libsefs-dev - Security Enhanced Linux file context management development
libsefs4 - Security Enhanced Linux file context management
libsetools-java - SETools Java bindings (architecture-independent)
libsetools-tcl - SETools Tcl bindings
libtomoyotools3 - lightweight Linux Mandatory Access Control system - library
policycoreutils - SELinux core policy utilities
python-selinux - Python bindings to SELinux shared libraries
python-semanage - Python bindings for SELinux policy management
python-sepolgen - Python module used in SELinux policy generation
python-sepolicy - Python binding for SELinux Policy Analyses
python-setools - SETools Python bindings
ruby-semanage - Ruby bindings to for SELinux policy management
selinux - Security-Enhanced Linux runtime support
selinux-basics - SELinux basic support
selinux-policy-default - Strict and Targeted variants of the SELinux policy
selinux-policy-dev - Headers from the SELinux reference policy for building modules
selinux-policy-doc - Documentation for the SELinux reference policy
selinux-policy-dummy - Empty Security-Enhanced Linux policy (dummy package)
selinux-policy-mls - MLS (Multi Level Security) variant of the SELinux policy
selinux-policy-src - Source of the SELinux reference policy for customization
selinux-policy-ubuntu - Security-Enhanced Linux Reference Policy
selinux-policy-ubuntu-dev - Security-Enhanced Linux Reference Policy Development Headers
selinux-policy-ubuntu-doc - Security-Enhanced Linux Reference Policy Documentation
selinux-utils - SELinux utility programs
setools - tools for Security Enhanced Linux policy analysis
setools-gui - GUI tools for Security Enhanced Linux policy analysis
```

Comment: http://selinuxproject.org for more info