# Selinux on Ubuntu Server 22.04

Tags: 22.04, apparmor, selinux

I uninstalled apparmor then installed and enabled Selinux.
But I'm getting errors, such as following;

```
Failed to start D-Bus System Message Bus
Failed to start Network Manager
```

Server is booting but I'm unable to connect to network since the network manager is not working.
I've tried `sudo restorecon -Rv /path/to/relabel && sudo reboot`, it didn't work.

Does anyone have any idea about fixing this ?

Comment: See here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/481293/selinux-implementation-in-ubuntu